# A command that takes a single numeric argument and prints out the day of the week based on the formula

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, terminal, bashrc

```
days=('Sunday''Monday')
days=('Tuesday''Wednesday')
days=('Thursday''Friday')
days=('Saturday')

for numbers in "S@";

do
        if [ $numbers -ge 0 ];
        then
                result=$(($numbers % 7))
                echo ${days[$result]}
        fi
shift
done
```

This is what I've got so far.

Comment: What's the formula?

Answer (score 3):

You're having trouble declaring your array:

```
days=('Sunday''Monday')          # this means days[0]="SundayMonday"
days=('Tuesday''Wednesday')      # this means days[0]="TuesdayWednesday"
days=('Thursday''Friday')        # this means days[0]="ThursdayFriday"
days=('Saturday')                # this means days[0]="Saturday"
```

You want this:

```
days=(Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday)
```

You can quote the day names if you want, the shell doesn't care since there's no shell expansions that can occur on them.

Next

```
for numbers in "S@";
```

That's a capital letter <kbd>S</kbd> not the required dollar sign <kbd>$</kbd>. so the first and only time through the loop, the value of `$numbers` will be the 2-character string `S@`

Other than that, looks OK.

Little nitpicky things:

- you don't need to end lines with semi-colons
- "numbers" is a bad variable name to hold just one number
- bash expands variables without the sigil in arithmetic expressions:

  ```
  result=$((numbers % 7))
  echo "${days[result]}"
  ```
- if you're iterating over the positional parameters, you don't need to refer to them:

  ```
  for number do echo "${days[number % 7]}"; done
  ```

I would write this as a shell function:

```
day_of_week() {
    local dow=$1
    if [[ $dow -lt 0 ]]; then 
        echo "error: pass a positive number"
        return 1
    fi
    local days=(Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday)
    echo "${days[dow]}"
}
```